# How can I change 'JUST' the navigation right bar button image?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue, rightbarbuttonitem

So right now, I have a right bar button in storyboard hooked up with a segue to another view controller. All the functions work fine here. (without code, all done through storyboard)

Now, I'm connecting to a webAPI call to see if the image needs to be changed. I have the code below:

```
 if ( json.count == 0) {
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"]]];
}
else
{
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification-new.png"]]];
}
```

So this all work fine and the image does change if there are more than 1 json data received. However, the button itself does not push to the new view controller

Answer (score 0):

You have created custom button. So now you have to set `UIBarButtonItem` s properties yourself

```
@property(nonatomic)         SEL   action;     // default is NULL
@property(nonatomic,assign)  id    target;     // default is nil
```

I can not check it right now but probably following should work:

```
UIBarButtonItem *originalRightButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification-new.png"]]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target = originalRightButton.target;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = originalRightButton.action;
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented what you did. It is not working but I think it's because I'm not understanding the action and target concept.

Comment: my original button is called goNotifications, declared as a property in my .h file. so I implemented the following code under this comment.

Comment: self.goNotifications = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification-new.png"]]];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target = self.goNotifications.target;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = self.goNotifications.action;

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom button along with its action and selector

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"];
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithImage:image];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(method) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=rightBtn;
```

In the button's target you can call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueName" sender:self];.
```

The segue has to be defined in storyboard with a name.

Hope this helps.